# Can you legitimately claim to have used intention-to-treat analysis in a cluster randomised trial if recruitment occurs after randomisation?

Tags: clinical-trials, medicine

In cluster-randomised clinical trials it is often the case that 'units', be they hospitals, practitioners or primary care centres etc., are randomised to the intervention or control arms prior to recruitment of the patients.

In this case, it can be expected that not 100% of patients in each cluster will consent to being involved in the trial. If patients are excluded after randomisation because they do not consent, can the authors legitimately claim to have used intention-to-treat analysis?

I feel that they cannot. However, this is based on a basic understanding that ITT is not possible if you exclude a patient after randomisation. Is there a more nuanced explanation for why they can or cannot use ITT?

Comment: Do the patients or investigators know to which cluster they are assigned prior to the consent process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If patients are excluded after randomisation because they do not consent, can the authors legitimately claim to have used intention-to-treat analysis? I feel that they cannot.

I agree with you. I don't think you can. The definition of Intention to Treat is well understood in the epidemiology and clinical trials literature: that patients are analysed according to their original allocation, regardless of the treatment they actually received. Accordingly, withdrawals, losses to follow-up, and crossovers are ignored in a strict intention to treat analysis.

There are now a plethora of studies that report that they used a "**modified intention to treat**" (mITT) analysis. One problem with this term is it is not well defined. In the Revised Cochrane Risk of Bias Tool for Randomized Trials (RoB 2.0) (Eldridge et al, 2016) the authors define mITT as:

> excluding participants if they did not receive a specified minimum amount of the intended intervention

An example of a recent cluster-randomised trial, that used mITT, is The IDEM Cluster Randomized Clinical Trial (Rolland et al, 2020):

> The modified intention-to-treat population, defined as all residents included who were followed up for at least 30 days, was used as the main analysis population for all efficacy end points (primary and secondary).

In 2004 an updated CONSORT statement warned that using the term "modified intention to treat" could lead to confusion and to inaccurate results (Ioannidis et al, 2004).

There have been several systematic reviews on this topic. Abraha & Montedori (2010) looked at 475 RCTs and concluded that:

> ...the increasing appearance of randomised controlled trials that report use of the modified intention to treat approach can be considered a shortcoming in the quality of reporting. The misuse of the intention to treat definition or the introduction of the modified intention to treat term cannot overcome problems related to missing data or protocol deviations. Inconsistent and multiple descriptions of the modified intention to treat approach may cause failure to achieve the standard intention to treat principle, which is the best method that preserves randomisation. We recommend the intention to treat approach as the method of choice for analysis in trials investigating the superiority of an intervention. Authors should provide complete information on post-randomisation exclusions if there are appropriate reasons to exclude participants.

In another review of 6 journals , Montedori et al (2011) looked at 367 RCTs and of these 197 were classified as ITT, 56 as mITT, and 114 as "no ITT" trials, and they found that:

> Trials classified as mITT were significantly more likely to be published in general medical journals, to report post-randomisation exclusions and to use placebo as a comparator. A total of 258 (69%) trials received complete or partial financial support from a for-profit agency and 216 of the trials (60%) reported results that favoured the treatment under investigation.

References:

Abraha, I., & Montedori, A. (2010). Modified intention to treat reporting in randomised controlled trials: systematic review. Bmj, 340.

Eldridge, S., Campbell, M., Campbell, M., Dahota, A., Giraudeau, B., Higgins, J., ... & Siegfried, N. (2016). Revised Cochrane risk of bias tool for randomized trials (RoB 2.0): additional considerations for cluster-randomized trials. Cochrane Methods. Cochrane Database Syst Rev, 10.

Ioannidis JP, Evans SJ, Gotzsche PC, O’Neill RT, Altman DG, Schulz K, et al. Better reporting of harms in randomized trials: an extension of the CONSORT statement. Ann Intern Med2004;141:781-8

Montedori, A., Bonacini, M. I., Casazza, G., Luchetta, M. L., Duca, P., Cozzolino, F., & Abraha, I. (2011). Modified versus standard intention-to-treat reporting: are there differences in methodological quality, sponsorship, and findings in randomized trials? A cross-sectional study. Trials, 12(1), 1-9.

Rolland, Y., Tavassoli, N., de Souto Barreto, P., Perrin, A., de Mazières, C. L., Rapp, T., ... & Andrieu, S. (2020). Systematic dementia screening by multidisciplinary team meetings in nursing homes for reducing emergency department transfers: the IDEM cluster randomized clinical trial. JAMA Network Open, 3(2), e200049-e200049.

Comment: Hmm here’s an analogous problem. You introduce some feature change on an ads platform and randomize advertisers. But some advertisers never log on during the experiment; so you intended to treat them but they never received the treatment. Same problem, different context. And I’d argue different conclusion.

Comment: Or you can just use daily activity as a variable to stratify on, so there’s not over/under representation of those that don’t log on during the experiment. Since logging on is correlated with treatment, could confound your results if you don’t stratify.

Comment: I was under the impression that losses-to-followup should be included in an ITT-analysis. According to the definition, once the subjects have been measured at baseline and randomized, they should be included in the analysis. Multiple imputation seems to be recommended frequently in these cases. When I searched the literature recently, there was no concensus on this issue, however.

Answer (score 5):

Cluster randomized trials are used when the treatment can be delivered "in total" such as when you educate all the staff in a hospital ward about a certain medical procedure, and you want to test whether there is benefit of such education.  The education of the staff informs how all the patients are treated by that staff.  We do a lot of cluster randomized trials and I have not seen many, if any, that excluded **any** patients from a cluster.

So one can argue that removing patients from clusters when the treatment is designed to be applied to a whole cluster is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Isn’t this what placebos are for? Use interest in participation as a screening factor for all randomization units, however, administer a placebo in the control group.

Robert’s answer initially agrees with you (ITT not reliable) but then captures a lot of scholarly skepticism on the alternative, mITT.

Interest/consent in the treatment might be correlated with the treatment effect, itself, so tread cautiously.

By removing observations where units do not consent to the treatment, you could overestimate the effectiveness of treatment.

For example, suppose radiation is used for cancer patients, but some patients with terminal illness opt out of radiation in favor of hospice, instead. They do not consent but note that consent is corrrlated with treatment efficacy. When consent is not present, the efficacy of radiation could be much lower. But by excluding lack of consent, you overestimate effect of radiation.

In this context, I’d prefer a multilevel model where the global coefficient for treatment effect is a function of two subgroup group coefficients, namely with-consent and without-consent (censored, imputed as zero.)

In this case, you could both differentiate the consent from non-consent contexts but also be aware of correlation between consent and treatment effect.